# Jqgrid compatabity issue with IE11

Tags: jqgrid

I am working on java. In my current project I am using jqgrid. Up to IE10 it is working fine, when i am testing on IE11 Jqgrid is not working. If I add particular URL to the compatibility view settings it is working fine. What might be the issue.. Please help me..

Comment: you should post more details. For example you wrote "on IE11 Jqgrid is not working". What exactly "not working"? Moreover it's extremely important to know which fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or old jqGrid in version <=4.7) you use and in which version. How looks HTML page which you use? (which `<!DOCTYPE ...` you use, do you use `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">` and so on).

Comment: I am using below meta tag <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> and jqgrid version is 4.5.1; Whenever page loads my jsp page needs to show jqgrid with some data but it is not loading and also not giving any error. Doctype is <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

Comment: First of all I would recommend you to try to change URL which loads jqGrid to URLs of free jqGrid 4.9.2 (see [the wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs)) to verify that you could have some problem which is already fixed in more recent version. Only if you really can't update jqGrid then you should provide the demo which can be used to debug the problem or at least post much more **details** of your implementation. I can't just guess what you do and what problem you could have.